# how to set language for ESC POS?

Tags: flutter, thermal-printer

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/234it.png)  [the result form ESC printer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6WgV.jpg)
In my case is Vietnamese. What can i do? It cannot print corectly.
i have search for CP in this link: https://sparkag.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/ESC_POS-AK912-English-Command-Specifications-V1.4.pdf
Is there any idea?

Comment: Please don't post code as an image - [ask]

Comment: The support code page information for the `ESC t` command in the printer manual you mentioned seems to be very specific, so why not add them to the flutter library's [esc_pos_utils/lib/resources/capabilities.json](https://github.com/andrey-ushakov/esc_pos_utils/blob/master/lib/resources/capabilities.json) and use them?