# Flutter: Can't print other language except English in thermal printer

Tags: flutter, dart, unicode, bluetooth, thermal-printer

I'm using the [blue_thermal_printer](https://pub.dev/packages/blue_thermal_printer) package for thermal printer. The problem is, when I try to print any other language other than English it prints some weird Chinese characters. I want to print Bangla characters to be specific.

The printer I'm using is Goojprt PT 210. It can print other languages when I use apps from the playstore.

Comment: The target device and language are different, but the content is the same as this question. [how to set language for ESC POS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77344169/9014308) It would be a good idea to check the code pages supported by the device and add the information to the configuration file. Like this. [esc_pos_utils/lib/resources/capabilities.json](https://github.com/andrey-ushakov/esc_pos_utils/blob/master/lib/resources/capabilities.json) If your device does not support your language's code page, you can simply convert everything you want to print into a single image and print it.